# Dimmer switch only dims one of two lights?

Tags: dimmer-switch

I have two ceiling lights in my living room controlled by a single switch. I wanted to install a dimmer switch to control/dim both of them. I installed the switch but the dimmer only dims one of the two lights. Although it will turn both lights on and off. Why? And is there a way to dim both lights?

Comment: what have you done to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: switched the two black wires to see it helped but did not. I have no other idea.

Comment: switched wires?    .... switch the light bulbs

Comment: Yes the orginal switch had two black and a ground. Thought I may have connected the wires to the wrong screw but got the same outcome. I forgot to mention that I did also try a different bulb but this made no difference.

Comment: i did not say replace the bad one .... switch the two, the working dimming one and the non dimming one. ... are they LED lights?

Comment: What kind of Lights are in the fixtures , LED, Halogen or Incandescent ? If LEd are they the same brand and are they dimmable ? If they are LED and Dimmable are they compatible with your dimmer switch ? Some Dimmers and LED's do not play nice together. If they are halogen or incandescent bulbs you might have a different issue .. Post more info by clicking the edit word under your post. BTW Welcome to StackExchange.